# Parent-Child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I show a parent-child relationship on a single page in Rails? I don't need a form as I simply want to show the information (no edits or updates required). The parent is customer and the child is orders. I want to able to select a customer, display some customer information such as address, and list all orders placed in row format. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your model associations set up properly..

In the controller,

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@orders = @customer.orders.all
```

Then in the view, use the orders variable.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what you want here. I am assuming you want to have a list of customers, and when you click on one of them, other page is being populated with its details. If so, the nicest solution is to use Ajax event which will get the details from a server and place it in given div. Action in customers_controller would be sth like:

```
def details
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])     
  render 'details', :layout => false               # remember to add view 'details'
                                                   # and appropriate route in routes.
end
```

and javascript (jQuery) (note it is not perfect ajax call, it doesn;t handle multiple clicks and other problems, but shoud get you started)

```
$('.customer-row').click(function() {
    customer_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/customers/" + customer_id + "/details",
        type: "get",
        success: function(details) {
            $('#customer_details').html(details)
         }
    });
});
```

Then in your basic view you need to have div with id 'customer_details' somewhere and each of customer row should look like  class="customer-row">.

In terms on how to access child objects inside details view it is as simple as:
    <% @customer.orders.each do |order|>
       # display order
    <% end %>